# Tkinter gets "main thread is not in main loop" if and only if there's a new pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I could run the threaded tkinkter without any issue if I didn't plot any new figure using matplotlib.pyplot afterwards. However, when I plot a new figure using pyplot, I'll get `main thread is not in main loop` for `BooleanVar` or any other tkinter var (`StringVar`, `IntVar`). I couldn't gets my head around it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class App(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        #Plotting this label has no issue at all
        l1= tk.Label(self.root, text="label 1", fg="white", bg='gray')
        l1.grid(column=0, row=r, columnspan=2)

        #The first line below is where issue lies
        c1v = tk.BooleanVar() 
        c1v.set(True)
        c1 = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text='checkbox 1', var=c1v, command=self.callback, anchor="w")
        c1.grid(sticky="W", column=0, row=r)

        self.root.mainloop()
```

The issue arise when I do something like this in my main.py:

```
app = App()

#Without this line below it runs perfectly fine
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(4, 4), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
```

What is the reason and how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `tkinter` and `matplotlib` have [known threading issues](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13293). This caught me out, and worked around by sending info back via globals to the plot in main thread.

Comment: That's unexpected of and bizarre. Do PyQt has such issue?

Comment: not sure on PyQt sorry.  Had gone far enough down the tk route to turn back!
Do you need to thread the whole program? Can you structure the program to have the interface/display via the main thread, then create the threads for your required task?  In my case I was dealing with audio playback, so I threaded the playback to avoid freezing the GUI while playing audio, and then sent back the playback position to update a plot with a progressbar.